# Internal Server Error when uploading video

Tags: typo3

I get INTERNAL SERVER ERROR when trying to upload a file that is larger than ~15 MB.

It happens on many Typo3 installations.

I have set `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` to 100 megabytes.

`max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` to 1000.

Typo3 6.2 and 7.6.

Answer (score 0):

You have also to look at the max execution time and max input time of php.

```
max_execution_time = value_in_seconds
max_input_time = value_in_seconds
```

If this is not helping, look at your apache error log file which error is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Other possible problems:

- Does the filename contain characters that are not compatible with your system?
- Is the user (you) allowed to upload to the upload directory?
- Are the permissions for the target folder correctly set (see Installtool -> Folder Structure)